# Are employers permitted to ask if a candidate smokes?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, privacy

I just encountered an employer on Stack Overflow that explicitly asks if a candidate smokes via their website. Although I am not a smoker, I find this to be a gross violation of a candidate's privacy. Does Stack Overflow permit employers to ask such questions? Also, is it legal for an employer to do this?

Comment: 1. What makes you think SO dictates what they can say on their own website? 2. That will depend on the country they're based in. And ultimately, if you don't like it, *don't apply*.

Comment: `Is it legal?` in what country?

Comment: Maybe they don't want non-smokers on their team?

Comment: Geez, enough with the snarky comments!  What if this same employer asked if you use antidepressants or if you are Catholic?

Comment: Which comments do you feel were "snarky"? For reference, in most job applications I've gone through, religious belief and medical status have been asked about. I think considering this a "gross violation of privacy" suggests you have a flair for the dramatic.

Comment: If the candidate does not smoke, they can pour on some lighter fluid and apply a match..

Comment: @Martin, and if it smokes then, then it's made of wood. And if it's made of wood...

Comment: From a quick web search refusing to hire smokers is [legal in the UK](http://www.worketiquette.co.uk/uk-smoking-rules-out-office.html)  and [in at least some states in the US](http://work.chron.com/can-employers-discriminate-against-smokers-18507.html)

Comment: At least in the USA, possibly elsewhere, health insurance is included in the benefits package.  That's a big chunk of money, $1,500 a month is not unusual.  Companies do about anything to cut down on that cost, like making a deal with the insurance company and promising to enforce a healthy lifestyle.  Look for a brag about gym benefits, that's another discount.  Smoking in the office is never allowed.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah - ban all the power supplies to the car park;)

Comment: ..and while we're at it, we could put all the Mac's out there too.

Comment: This question is better suited for http://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Employers can ask anything they want within the applicable laws for the country where the company operates from.

If what they put on their website or in their applications forms is legal is to decide for lawyers or law enforcement agencies. It is not a role for Stack Overflow, Inc. to be a judge on that.

If you want to work for companies that ask such stuff is up to your own morale and principles. And how hard you need the money ...